# Updating a complex object with linq and Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4.1

I have an object, called Order, which has several properties which are also objects. when I update the Order object the simple properties are updated correctly, but the complex ones (which reside in different tables) are not being updated and instead new ones are created. What am I doing wrong. Also, when I try to get a multiple items property (Items in this example) it returns null and not the saved items.

Code Sample:

```
[DataContract]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DataMember]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    #region Order Details

    [DataMember]
    public int? ReferenceNumber { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Status CurrentStatus { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime? CurrentStatusUpdatedOn { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [MaxLength(1024)] public string ArchiveFileName { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public double TotalPrice { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public bool DigitallySigned { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int DigitalSigningReferenceId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Priority Priority { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
            .....
            }

[DataContract]
public class Item : IItem
{
    [DataMember]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Order ParentOrder { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual ItemType Type { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string ItemReference { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int FeeReference { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }
            ....
           }

private static bool UpdateOrderDetails(Order order, DatabaseContext context)
    {
        var savedOrder =
            context.Orders.Include("Priority").Include("CurrentStatus").Where(o => o.Id == order.Id).FirstOrDefault();

            //context.Orders.SingleOrDefault(o => o.Id == order.Id);
        if (savedOrder != null)
        {
            savedOrder.Priority = order.Priority;
            savedOrder.ReferenceNumber = order.ReferenceNumber;
            savedOrder.ShohamId = order.ShohamId;
            savedOrder.TotalPrice = order.TotalPrice;
            savedOrder.UpdatedOn = DateTime.Now;
            savedOrder.CreatedOn = order.CreatedOn;
            savedOrder.ArchiveFileName = order.ArchiveFileName;
            savedOrder.ClientEmail = order.ClientEmail;
            savedOrder.ClientFirstName = order.ClientFirstName;
            savedOrder.ClientIdentificationNumber = order.ClientIdentificationNumber;
            savedOrder.ClientIdentificationType = order.ClientIdentificationType;
            savedOrder.ClientLastName = order.ClientLastName;
            savedOrder.ClientPrimaryPhone = order.ClientPrimaryPhone;
            savedOrder.ClientSecondaryPhone = order.ClientSecondaryPhone;
            savedOrder.CurrentStatus = order.CurrentStatus;
            savedOrder.CurrentStatusUpdatedOn = order.CurrentStatusUpdatedOn;
            savedOrder.DigitallySigned = order.DigitallySigned;
            savedOrder.DigitalSigningReferenceId = order.DigitalSigningReferenceId;

            if (order.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in order.Items)
                {
                    var savedItem = savedOrder.Items.Single(x => x.ItemReference == item.ItemReference);
                    if (savedItem != null)
                    {
                        savedItem.Price = item.Price;
                        savedItem.Quantity = item.Quantity;
                    }
                }
            }

            context.Entry(savedOrder).State = EntityState.Modified;
            var i = context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: are `order` and `savedOrder` created from same context? is the `order` object detached from context?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to insert new objects for your navigation properties you must attach them to the context before you assign the values. For your items collection problem you need to include the collection when you query. Including the other two navigation properties is not necessary and setting the state to `Modified` manually neither in your example. For `Include` you can use a strongly typed version in EF 4.1 with a lambda expression:

```
private static bool UpdateOrderDetails(Order order, DatabaseContext context)
{
    var savedOrder = context.Orders.Include(o => o.Items)
                         .Where(o => o.Id == order.Id)
                         .FirstOrDefault();

    if (savedOrder != null)
    {
        context.Priorities.Attach(order.Priority);
        context.CurrentStati.Attach(order.CurrentStatus);

        savedOrder.Priority = order.Priority;

        // etc.

        var i = context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Slauma, I am trying your way and I get the following error:
_A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Moj.FE.Data.Order' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Items'._

Comment: @Etchin: Strange. What is `Items` then? You are using `order.Items` in your code. Can you show how the `Order` class is defined in your model? (You can edit your question to show the class.)

Comment: @Etchin: Very strange. This should really work. Do you have any Fluent API code? How does your context class look like? What is `IItem`? Does your Items table in the database have a foreign key to the order, something like `ParentOrder_Id` or `Order_Id`?

Comment: @Slauma: Have you tried adding
    using System.Data.Entity;
to the Class that contains the 
   UpdateOrderDetails()
method?  This fixed a similar issue I was having, where the 
   Include()
method would not take a lambda expression (ie only works with a string containing the name of the navigation property.

Comment: @HOCA: I think, this can't be the reason. It's a runtime error. If `using System.Data.Entity` would be missing we would get an error at compile time.